# Access lightning calendar on Home record page

Tags: lightning-experience, calendar, lightning-home-page, record-home-page

I have a requirement to display out of box calendar on the home record page. So does lightning feature allows us to display lightning custom calendar as a component on record page?

Thanks

Comment: Best components I have found - http://lightningstrike.io